# How can I solve System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in FROM clause.'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oledb, oledbconnection

I run the VS file to the following code. After start running, it shows System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in FROM clause.'
How can I solve it? Thank you.

```
public partial class OrderForm : Form
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=db_users.accdb");
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataReader dr;



    public OrderForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadOrder();
    }

    public void LoadOrder()
    {
        double total = 0;
        int i = 0;
        dgvOrder.Rows.Clear();
        command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT OrderID,OrderDate,O.[ProductID],P.[ProdName], O.[CustID], C.[CustName], Qty, Price, Total FROM [Order] AS O JOIN [Customer] AS C ON O.[CustID]=C.[CustID] JOIN [Product] AS P ON O.[ProductID]=P.[ProductID] WHERE CONCAT(OrderID,OrderDate,O.[ProductID],P.[ProdName], O.[CustID], C.[CustName]) LIKE '%" +txtSearch.Text+"%'", con);
        con.Open();
        dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            i++;
            dgvOrder.Rows.Add(i, dr[0].ToString(), Convert.ToDateTime(dr[1].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), dr[4].ToString(), dr[5].ToString(), dr[6].ToString(), dr[7].ToString(), dr[8].ToString());
            total += Convert.ToInt32(dr[8].ToString());
        }
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
        lblQty.Text = i.ToString();
        lblTotal.Text = total.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: Please attach the structure of your database related table or the SQL statement when you created the table.

Comment: Side note: do not cache the connection, command or reader objects. Create when needed, dispose with `using`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the information provided by your code, I have created 3 tables to simply reproduce your code.The data in the table in the database is filled in casually, please understand.

form page:

[image]

By clicking the "Query Condition" button, you can generate data in the form by querying the database.

this is the result:

[image]

The operation of the database is encapsulated by the entity class, which is the code that encapsulates the database entity class.

```
internal class Dao
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    public SqlConnection connection()
    {
       // write database connection string
        string connStr = "Data source=localhost;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=sa;Password=123456";
        conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();
        return conn;
    }

    public SqlCommand command(string sql)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection());
        return cmd;
    }

    public int Execute(string sql)
    {
        return command(sql).ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public SqlDataReader read(string sql)
    {
        return command(sql).ExecuteReader();
    }
    public void DaoClose()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
 }
```

By clicking the button, the function of querying the database is realized and the corresponding data is generated.

```
   //Read the data from the data and display it in the table control
    public void Table()
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();// clear old data
        Dao dao = new Dao();
        double total = 0;
        int i = 0;
        string sql = $"SELECT OrderID,OrderDate,O.[ProductID],P.[ProdName], O.[CustID], C.[CustName], Qty, Price, Total FROM [Orders] AS O JOIN [Customer] AS C ON O.[CustID]=C.[CustID] JOIN [Product] AS P ON O.[ProductID]=P.[ProductID] WHERE CONCAT(OrderID,OrderDate,O.[ProductID],P.[ProdName], O.[CustID], C.[CustName]) LIKE  '%{textBox1.Text}%'";
        IDataReader dr = dao.read(sql);
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            i++;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, dr[0].ToString(), Convert.ToDateTime(dr[1].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), dr[4].ToString(), dr[5].ToString(), dr[6].ToString(), dr[7].ToString(), dr[8].ToString());
            total += Convert.ToInt32(dr[8].ToString());
        }
        dr.Close();
        dao.DaoClose();
        lblQty.Text = i.ToString();
        lblTotal.Text = total.ToString();
    }

   

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Table();
    }
```

Through the test, there is no problem with the sql statement, the function of database query is realized and the data is successfully displayed. Check the database connection string. Whether the fields of the sql statement correspond to the database. Hope that helps you.

Comment: my database is same as sql but still can't show. Table is {
Customer: CustID,CustName
Order:OrderID,OrderDate,ProductID,CustID,Qty,Price,Total
Product:ProductID,ProdName }

Comment: @yannis I tested it for you again today. I only changed your sql statement from txtSearch.Text to textBox1.Text, and implemented the query to the database through the value passed in from the text box, which was also successful. You could try using "textBox", or use the sql entity class encapsulated by the answer above.